# loop cut not working

Tags: modeling, edges

hi i have been working on a tutorial (link is below) and when i try loop cutting this is what i get[image]

before loop cuting

[image: before cutting]

after loop cutting

thanks in advance

tutorial: https://www.blendernation.com/2020/09/27/car-modeling-for-beginners-in-blender-2-8x/

Comment: i tried after i had seen your post but it doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: Did you try to lower (or uncheck) the "merge" value of the mirror modifier?

Comment: yep, it solved the problem thanks

Comment: Idk what u did wrong I suggest u this tutorial : https://youtu.be/w14W84-nyyM

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is likely caused by the *Merge* option of your *Mirror* modifier. This option causes vertices within a certain range to merge together.

You can just uncheck the *Merge* option. Setting it to even lower number might help too.

[image: Mirror modifier menu]